# Does Python's GzipFile class have a default maximum buffer size?

Tags: python, gzip, base64, buffer, compression

I am attempting to recover/decode a string that has been gzipped and then base64-encoded.  Currently, I am using Python's gzip module -- and in particular, the GzipFile class -- to decompress the file-like object that is the result of the base64-decoding.  Under Python 2.7.3:

```
import gzip
from base64 import b64decode
from cStringIO import StringIO

for page_content in open(page_content_file, 'rb'):
    page_content_decoded = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=StringIO(b64decode(page_content))).read()
```

The issue I'm having is that I'm hitting some sort of upper limit during the gzip decompression stage.  I've broken out this long statement and tested the individual components... the length of the page_content does not get limited at the base64decode() or StringIO() levels.

(Apologies for the image links, I'm a new user and don't have enough reputation to attach images).

Here is how the [original, compressed page_content lengths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sX7fP.png) look, and the [lengths of the page_content_decoded strings look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OR9Qr.png) like:

Obviously, the output lengths are longer since I'm decompressing them; however, it's evident that I'm hitting some sort of maximum buffer size or max_bytes or something.  Is there a value that I can set for the gzip decompression?  Do I need to read the gzip file in chunks and concatenate those chunks?  (I've tried my hand at both of these approaches without success).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You should probably look into using the lower level [zlib](http://docs.python.org/library/zlib.html) module, more specifically its [decompressobj](http://docs.python.org/library/zlib.html#zlib.decompressobj) which allows decompressing data streams that won’t fit into memory at once and where you can tweak the used buffer size. If you point me to the url of the original compressed page I can post an answer for you.